# ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 2746 and input n_features is 2854

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

```
**

# Preprocessing original dataframe
    def preprocess_df(dataframe):
        x = dataframe.copy()
        try:
            customer_id = x['CustomerID']
            del x['CustomerID'] # Don't need in ML DF
        except:
            print("already removed customerID")
        ml_dummies = pd.get_dummies(x)
        ml_dummies.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
    
        # import random done above
        ml_dummies['---randomColumn---'] = np.random.randint(0,1000, size=len(ml_dummies))
    
        try:
            label = ml_dummies['Churn Label']
            del ml_dummies['Churn Label']
        except:
            print("label already removed.")
        return ml_dummies, customer_id, label
    
    original_df = preprocess_df(df)
    
    output_df = original_df[0].copy()
    output_df.shape
    output_df['---randomColumn---']
    output_df['prediction'] = clf.predict_proba(output_df)[:,1]
    output_df['Churn Label'] = original_df[2]
    output_df['CustomerID'] = original_df[1]
```

this is my code and it gives me this error
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 2746 and input n_features is 2854

**

Answer (score 0):

Only possibility i can think of is:

1. Let's say you got a dummy variable for something called `Languages`.
2. Your initial `train` dataset to train/fit your model `clf` consisted of `Languages : English, French, Python.`, Thus creating three dummy columns - `Language-English, Language-French, Language-Python.`

3. However, the `df` you're using for preprocess_df only consisted of `Language : English, French, Korean, Java` , we're missing `Language-Python` column the original train dataset had, and has `Language-Korean` and `Language-Java` the original trainset didn't have, meaning the `ml_dummies` you're returning is either/both missing some columns or have extra columns..

Assuming my assumptions were correct, my solution for this was :

1. If your train and predict is in same code, you should use your train data for your preprocess_df instead.
2. If unavailable/alternatively, You need to create and save list of column names **from a data that was used to train/fit a model** after dummy variable creation. THEN you can fit your willing-to-predict data to those column names.

let me know if i misunderstood.

in response to your comment :

1. You have a dataset to train a model, `train_data`, which consists of (say) 100 columns.
2. After your `preprocess_df`, You'll have `x_train` **which consists of 2746 columns** after dummy variable.
3. Before doing `model(clf).train` or `model(clf).fit`, save your x_train's shape somewhere, say `model_input_columns = x_train.columns`, or even on a file if you're trying to use it in different module/future.
4. For the DataFrame you're actually trying to predict, which probably also has 100 columns, say `predict_data`, do `preprocess_df(predict_data)`
5. This will give you `x_predict_data` which consists of 2854 columns.
6. Now to actually predict using model `clf`, the **2854 columns dataframe you have** (to be predicted), somehow **needs to be transformed to a 2746 columns dataframe**. This is where you need your `model_input_columns` we saved before.
7. There are probably many ways to do this and honestly I'm not exactly an expert in this field, but if you'd still take my probably-not-so-ideal way :

```
actual_x_input_for_prediction = pd.DataFrame()
default = 0

for column in model_input_columns :
            if column in x_predict_data :
                actual_x_input_for_prediction[column] = x_predict_data[column]
            else :
                actual_x_input_for_prediction[column] = [default] * len( x_predict_data)

clf.predict(actual_x_input_for_prediction)
```

Comment: i understand what ur trying to say but i didn't understand what should i do

Comment: @mazen I have edited the answer, check if that's what you wanted